# jTab not rendering correctly

Tags: bug, jtab

The jTab notation

%5/1.5/1.7/3.5/1.6/2.5/1[I] %3/1.5/3.3/1.4/2.3/1.3/1[IV] %5/1.7/3.5/1.6/2.5/1.5/1[V]

Does not render properly. It results in

```
%5/1.5/1.7/3.5/1.6/2.5/1[I] %3/1.5/3.3/1.4/2.3/1.3/1[IV] %5/1.7/3.5/1.6/2.5/1.5/1[V]
```

As opposed to

[image: jTab image (screenshot) from https://jtab.tardate.com/]

This code comes from [How to interpret this blues-like chord sequence?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/114097/how-to-interpret-this-blues-like-chord-sequence)

The screenshot image of the correct display was generated at https://jtab.tardate.com/