# Can this stack exchange incorporate a basic notation add-in so that responses are easier to understand?

Tags: feature-request

It's difficult to read/interpret musical notation/shorthand in responses.  I could give plenty of examples of times when the QWERTY keyboard was a less-than-ideal tool for expressing musical ideas, but i'm sure you are just as familiar.

Comment: We already have jtab and abcjs.  Is there something specific they don't cover that you need?

Comment: Ah, it looks like what I need is to learn how to use those!  I've never heard of that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a link to our [documentation for ABCjs](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2782/documentation-for-abcjs).

Here is a link to our [jTab and ABCjs formatting sandbox](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2581/jtab-and-abcjs-formatting-sandbox), where you can try things out and practice.

For ABCjs, I frequently use the

- [ABCjs editor](https://www.abcjs.net/abcjs-editor.html)
- [ABCjs standard](http://abcnotation.com/wiki/abc:standard:v2.1)

**NOTE:** At the time of this post, [jTab appears to be broken](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3708/jtab-not-rendering-correctly).